# How to create a treeview in google chrome extension

Tags: treeview, google-chrome-extension

How can i create a google chrome extension with a treeview? something like the favourite manager.

I've searched, but with no luck.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't do this directly in chrome. You may want to use a javascript library for that. I'd use [jsTree](http://www.webxplorer.org/jsTree/), but there are other possibilities, like those in [this list](http://www.queness.com/post/1138/10-javascriptcss-treeview-and-sitemap-plugins-and-tutorials).